# C# 'Secure' Login Via MySQL Database Without MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I want to be able to login to my application by using a MySQL db without having the MySQL credentials within the source code.

I have looked into posting C# data to a PHP file but I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for (I could seem to fetch values from it) - could you point me in the right direction to get this setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to post to a PHP file, ASP file, or web service to avoid coding your credentials. Also I wouldn't recommend fetching all the usernames and passwords to send back to your app, if that's what you're talking about doing anyhow.

This is a good tutorial for C#, mySQL, and PHP

www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2RJPLBTyzs

Comment: Thanks, the video wasn't brilliant - but I managed to get it working.